# How to write Debezium Connector Configuration and Debezium Listener for mongoDB in spring-boot and before, after payload as JSON?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, debezium, cdc

Could anyone please provide the sample code in spring-boot for Debezium connector Listeners class and configuration class for MongoDB which provide the changed data payload in Json.
Thanks in advance!

Here's my Debezium Connector Listner:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class DebeziumListener {

    private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private final DebeziumEngine<RecordChangeEvent<SourceRecord>> debeziumEngine;

    public DebeziumListener(Configuration mongoConnector) {
        this.debeziumEngine = DebeziumEngine.create(ChangeEventFormat.of(Connect.class))
                .using(mongoConnector.asProperties()).notifying(t -> {
                    try {
                        log.error("Running Debezium Engine.");
                        handleChangeEvent(t);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Error on running Debezium Engine.");
                        log.error(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }).build();
    }

    /**
     * It Records any Change Event in database based on DebeziumConnectorConfig.
     * 
     * @param sourceRecordChangeEvent
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void handleChangeEvent(RecordChangeEvent<SourceRecord> sourceRecordChangeEvent) throws IOException {
        SourceRecord sourceRecord = sourceRecordChangeEvent.record();
        Struct sourceRecordChangeValue = (Struct) sourceRecord.value();

        if (sourceRecordChangeValue != null) {
            Operation operation = Operation.forCode((String) sourceRecordChangeValue.get(OPERATION));
            if (operation != Operation.READ) {
                // Handling Update & Insert operations.
                String records = operation == Operation.DELETE ? BEFORE : AFTER;
                Struct struct = (Struct) sourceRecordChangeValue.get(records);
                Map<String, Object> payload = struct.schema().fields().stream().map(Field::name)
                        .filter(fieldName -> struct.get(fieldName) != null)
                        .map(fieldName -> Pair.of(fieldName, struct.get(fieldName)))
                        .collect(toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue));
                log.info("Changes have been detected for product id: {} with Operation: {}",
                        Optional.ofNullable(payload).map(p -> p.get("productId")).orElse(null), operation.name());
                log.info(payload);
                log.debug("Updated Data: {} with Operation: {}", payload, operation.name());
            }
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void start() {
        this.executor.execute(debeziumEngine);

    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void stop() throws IOException {
        if (this.debeziumEngine != null) {
            this.debeziumEngine.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the connector config file:

```
@Configuration
public class DebeziumConnectorConfig {

    @Bean
    public io.debezium.config.Configuration mongoConnector() throws IOException {
        File offsetStorageTempFile = File.createTempFile("offsets_", ".dat");
        File dbHistoryTempFile = File.createTempFile("dbhistory_", ".dat");
        return io.debezium.config.Configuration.create().
with("name", "mongo-connector")
                .with("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector")
                .with("offset.storage", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
                .with("offset.storage.file.filename", offsetStorageTempFile.getAbsolutePath())
                .with("database.history.file.filename", dbHistoryTempFile.getAbsolutePath())
                .with("mongodb.members.auto.discover", "false")
                .with("tasks.max", "1")
                .with("mongodb.hosts", "rs0/localhost,27017")
                .with("mongodb.name", "products_topic")
                .with("errors.log.include.messages", "true")
                .with("capture.mode", "change_streams_update_full")
                .with("collection.include.list", "myCollection")
                .with("database.include.list", "myDb")
                .with("schema", "true")
                .with("heartbeat.interval.ms", 0)
                .with("database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" , "kafka:9092")
                .with( "transforms", "route")
                .with( "transforms.route.type" , "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter")
                 .with( "transforms.route.regex" , "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)")
                 .with( "transforms.route.replacement" , "$3")
                .build();
    }
}
```

and after the application startup server keeps on logging the below logs:

7
2022-05-13 09:01:14.455  INFO 15452 --- [ica-set-monitor] i.d.c.mongodb.ReplicaSetDiscovery        : Checking current members of replica set at rs0/localhost,27017
2022-05-13 09:01:14.456  INFO 15452 --- [ica-set-monitor] i.d.c.mongodb.ReplicaSetDiscovery        : Checking current members of replica set at rs0/localhost,27017

Comment: Could you instead share what you've tried and what hasn't worked?

Comment: @Naros i have added the files that i have tried please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you have a typo in your `mongodb.hosts` configuration property.  It should have a value of:

```
rs0/localhost:27017
```

(Note the `:` rather than the `,` you have in your question).

Comment: Thanks @Naros now my connector is working fine and Connector is able to detect the CREATE (c) and DELETE(d) operations perfectly but while updating the document its not working and throwing the error:
 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List com.mongodb.client.model.changestream.UpdateDescription.getTruncatedArrays()'

is there anything that i am missing in Configuration?

Comment: It would appear you're using an older driver that may no longer be compatible with MongoDB with change streams.  Please make sure you're using the right driver version.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Naros after updating the driver it worked like a charm.